# one reducer vs multiple reducer with post processing for counting words and sorting. Which one is more efficient and scalable?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am doing word count with sorting(by value) in one MapReduce job. The two ways to achieve this:

1. Using one reducer and saving everything in HashMap in reduce function and sorting everything by value in cleanUp function and then writing everything to file.
2. Using multiple reducers and saving word count in HDFS after MapReduce job. After MR sorting everything using Java.

Which solution is better in the sense of efficiency and scalability.

Answer (score 0):

The second variant does not provide a global sort, e.g. if you have 2 reducers, result files could be

```
part-r-00000
word1    1
word2    3

part-r-00001
word3    2
word4    5
```

Even if you sort each file by values, it will be hard to iterate over the words in descending order `word4-word2-word3-word1`. You can make some tricks will parallel reading though.

On the other hand, single reducer will perform slower, because it will have to handle all the data. Also it's possible you won't have enough memory to keep all the data in reducer JVM heap.

I'd choose single reducer if it is possible.

Comment: In the second variant, sorting can be done through Java Collection.sort() by accessing every file  (part-r-00000, part-r-00001, ...) and getting values and storing them in a HashMap. Every entry of hashmap can be added to a list and can be sorted using Collection.sort(). Do you think this would be possible if we are dealing with big files?

Comment: @HamzaMalik what's the point to read all files by java program after MR job if you can do the same thing in a reducer?

Comment: Because in one MR job I can only find the frequency of the words (my reducer sums all the final frequencies) and that is written back to HDFS. I further want to sort the key value output by value but by key(words).

Comment: @HamzaMalik you didn't understand me. I say that variant 1 with sort by value in reducer cleanup is the same thing as to read all reducer files in java program and sort them by value.

Comment: alright, do you think it would be same in sense of performance?

Comment: @HamzaMalik i think hadoop solution will be faster

Answer (score 0):

For a generalized workload (including word count) having one reducer is not a good idea as it is an obvious bottleneck (i.e., all multiple mapper outputs go to it). So the **option 2** is preferable.

Also, note that a reducer output is sorted so 'HashMap', 'cleanUp' are redundant in the **option 1**.

Comment: By sort, I mean sort by value, updated in question as well.